# 12 hour clock, the 12th hour in decimal

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, arrays

I have a 12 hour clock that calculates the difference between two times in decimal. It runs through the loop below but after testing I saw that when I type in a time between 12:00 and 12:59 (AM or PM) it posts the completely wrong time. The problem is that the 12th hour is a special case and doesn't need to have 12 added or subtracted from it. How can I fix this so it posts the correct time in decimal?

Also since I'm posting this I have another question; how can I easily calculate the total time in decimal?

Here's a picture of the GUI so you have an idea of what we're dealing with.
http://imgur.com/y7JezcC

```
protected void CalculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Initializing
    TextBox[] textboxesIn = new TextBox[7];
    TextBox[] textboxesOut = new TextBox[7];
    DropDownList[] dropdownIn = new DropDownList[7];
    DropDownList[] dropdownOut = new DropDownList[7];
    Label[] labels = new Label[7];

    //Week 1 in textboxes
    textboxesIn[0] = MondayW1InTextBox;
    textboxesIn[1] = TuesdayW1InTextBox;
    textboxesIn[2] = WednesdayW1InTextBox;
    textboxesIn[3] = ThursdayW1InTextBox;
    textboxesIn[4] = FridayW1InTextBox;
    textboxesIn[5] = SaturdayW1InTextBox;
    textboxesIn[6] = SundayW1InTextBox;

    //Week 1 out textboxes
    textboxesOut[0] = MondayW1OutTextBox;
    textboxesOut[1] = TuesdayW1OutTextBox;
    textboxesOut[2] = WednesdayW1OutTextBox;
    textboxesOut[3] = ThursdayW1OutTextBox;
    textboxesOut[4] = FridayW1OutTextBox;
    textboxesOut[5] = SaturdayW1OutTextBox;
    textboxesOut[6] = SundayW1OutTextBox;

    //Week 1 in drop down list
    dropdownIn[0] = MondayW1InDropDown;
    dropdownIn[1] = TuesdayW1InDropDown;
    dropdownIn[2] = WednesdayW1InDropDown;
    dropdownIn[3] = ThursdayW1InDropDown;
    dropdownIn[4] = FridayW1InDropDown;
    dropdownIn[5] = SaturdayW1InDropDown;
    dropdownIn[6] = SundayW1InDropDown;

    //Week 1 out drop down list
    dropdownOut[0] = MondayW1OutDropDown;
    dropdownOut[1] = TuesdayW1OutDropDown;
    dropdownOut[2] = WednesdayW1OutDropDown;
    dropdownOut[3] = ThursdayW1OutDropDown;
    dropdownOut[4] = FridayW1OutDropDown;
    dropdownOut[5] = SaturdayW1OutDropDown;
    dropdownOut[6] = SundayW1OutDropDown;

    //Week 1 labels
    labels[0] = MondayW1Label;
    labels[1] = TuesdayW1Label;
    labels[2] = WednesdayW1Label;
    labels[3] = ThursdayW1Label;
    labels[4] = FridayW1Label;
    labels[5] = SaturdayW1Label;
    labels[6] = SundayW1Label;

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(textboxesIn[i].Text.PadLeft(4, '0'), "HHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        string timestring = dt.ToString("h:mm");
        labels[i].Text = timestring;

        DateTime timeIn = DateTime.ParseExact(textboxesIn[i].Text.PadLeft(4, '0'), "HHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        DateTime timeOut = DateTime.ParseExact(textboxesOut[i].Text.PadLeft(4, '0'), "HHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        if (dropdownIn[i].SelectedValue == "PM")
        {
            timeIn = timeIn.AddHours(12);
        }

        if (dropdownOut[i].SelectedValue == "PM")
        {
            timeOut = timeOut.AddHours(12);
        }
        labels[i].Text = (timeOut - timeIn).TotalHours.ToString("f2");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just add the AM/PM to the time string and use the format "HHmm tt"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In every case, when you write 1 to 11, it would be AM by default and you can sum 12 hs, but when you write 12 always will be PM (AM would be 00), So:

1PM + 12 = 13

2PM + 12 = 14

..

11PM + 12 = 23

//Now your strange result:

12:45(PM) + 12 = 24:45 => 00:45 but one day after

3:00(PM) + 12 = 15

15hs (Day 0) - 00:45 (Day 1)  is your negative result.

An easy way is resting 12hs when 12 is the case.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(textboxesIn[i].Text.PadLeft(4, '0'), "HHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        string timestring = dt.ToString("h:mm");
        labels[i].Text = timestring;

        DateTime timeIn = DateTime.ParseExact(textboxesIn[i].Text.PadLeft(4, '0'), "HHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        DateTime timeOut = DateTime.ParseExact(textboxesOut[i].Text.PadLeft(4, '0'), "HHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        if(timeIn.Hour == 12) timeIn = timeIn.AddHours(-12);  //a easy way

        if (dropdownIn[i].SelectedValue == "PM")
        {
            timeIn = timeIn.AddHours(12);
        }

        if (dropdownOut[i].SelectedValue == "PM")
        {
            timeOut = timeOut.AddHours(12);
        }
        labels[i].Text = (timeOut - timeIn).TotalHours.ToString("f2");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
DateTime timeIn = DateTime.ParseExact(textboxesIn[i].Text.PadLeft(4, '0') + dropdownIn[i].SelectedValue.Text, "hhmm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You have to change HH to hh because you cant Parse 12AM to HH.
After that you can timeOut - timeIn without problem.